# EFS symlink fails while deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, config, amazon-efs, ebextensions

So I use AWS Elastic Beanstalk to serve my PHP application. I want to mount EFS to have permanent storage for the images uploaded via my application.
I have created .ebextensions folder and created one file called mount.config with the below code

```
packages:
  yum:
    nfs-utils: []
    jq: []
files:
  "/tmp/mount-efs.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      mkdir -p /mnt/efs
      EFS_NAME=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | jq -r '.EFS_NAME')
      mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 $EFS_NAME:/ /mnt/efs || true
      mkdir -p /mnt/efs/questions
      chown webapp:webapp /mnt/efs/questions
commands:
  01_mount:
    command: "/tmp/mount-efs.sh"
container_commands:
  01-symlink-uploads:
    command: ln -s /mnt/efs/questions /var/app/ondeck/images/
```

Everything is working fine until the last line where it fails to create a symlink.

What I have tried so far:

- Running the command directly on the machine while changing ondeck -> current. This works fine.
- Removing the EC2 instance and adding a new one. Still failing

In the logs I see

> ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/app/current/images/questions': No such file or directory

Any suggestion what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it by replacing **ondeck** with **staging**

And adding this line under **container_commands:**

```
  01-change-permission:
    command: chmod -R 777 /var/app/staging/images
```